# What does the phrase "it is up to us to ﬂesh it out" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, idiom-meaning

What does the phrase "it is up to us to ﬂesh it out" mean?

Can you suggest any synonyms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the *New Oxford American Dictionary*:

> **up to**: the duty, responsibility, or choice of (someone): *it was up to
>   them to gauge the problem*

> **flesh something out**: add more details to something that exists only in a draft or  outline form: *the theorists have fleshed out a variety of scenarios*.

So this sentence means (it may not fit exactly, you did not give much context): **“it is our responsibility to complete this proposal”**

Comment: "implement" .NE. "flesh it out".  Since we don't know what "it" is.  And even if we did... "flesh out the proposal" does not mean to implement it.  It means to make it a complete proposal, while it's just a rough sketch now.  You can only implement a fully-spelled out proposal (agile methodologies are ignored here ;-))

Comment: note that the original phrase is **"up to us"** so the meaning is “it is **our** responsibility to complete this proposal”

Answer (score 6):

**"flesh it out"** means to add flesh to the body of something.  That is to say, fatten it up, make it more substantial, take a bare bones skeleton project/example and make it a fully formed entity.

In short it is using the metaphor of a body, a skeleton, that needs flesh to be complete - to refer to anything that is just the basic structure and needs to be filled in, completed, made whole.